# How to change icon of file | Python

Tags: python, icons

How can I change icon of any exe file, using python. I searched in Internet, but there are questions only about Tkinter, PyQt5. I need to change any exe icon.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just needed to change your search terms. There are already libraries that do this, e.g. https://github.com/avast/pe_tools .

Comment: Doing in python, what shold I do with ```100 ICON "new_icon.ico"```